# React-Native Expo 35: Passing Data From Component to Component with Async

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I am trying to pass streamURL from (Player.js) component to my audio player (PlayButton.js) component. Normally, i'd put it in the componentDidMount but that doesn't seem to work, I think because it's async?

**Player.js** component (simplified for this question):

```
render() {
   const streamURL = "http://stream.mydomain.com:8020/;mp3";
      return (
         <PlayButton streamURL={streamURL} />
      );
   }
```

**PlayButton.js** This react component needs to receive streamurl. Right now URL is hard-coded which works fine.

```
import React from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
import styled from "styled-components";

const streamURL = "http://stream.mydomain.com:8020/;mp3";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isPlaying: false,
    playbackInstance: null,
    currentIndex: 0,
    volume: 1.0,
    isBuffering: true
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: false,
        interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
        shouldDuckAndroid: true,
        staysActiveInBackground: true,
        playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false
      });

      this.loadAudio();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  async componentWillUnmount() {
    const { playbackInstance } = this.state;
    await playbackInstance.pauseAsync();
  }

  async loadAudio() {
    const { currentIndex, isPlaying, volume } = this.state;

    try {
      const playbackInstance = new Audio.Sound();
      const source = {
        uri: streamURL
      };

      const status = {
        shouldPlay: isPlaying,
        volume: volume
      };

      playbackInstance.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(this.onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
      await playbackInstance.loadAsync(source, status, false);
      this.setState({
        playbackInstance
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  onPlaybackStatusUpdate = status => {
    this.setState({
      isBuffering: status.isBuffering
    });
  };

  handlePlayPause = async () => {
    const { isPlaying, playbackInstance } = this.state;
    isPlaying
      ? await playbackInstance.pauseAsync()
      : await playbackInstance.playAsync();

    this.setState({
      isPlaying: !isPlaying
    });
  };

  renderFileInfo() {
    const { playbackInstance, currentIndex } = this.state;
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PlayButtonContainer>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePlayPause}>
          <Buttons>
            {this.state.isPlaying ? (
              <Ionicons name="ios-pause" size={64} color="#fff" />
            ) : (
              <Ionicons name="ios-play-circle" size={64} color="#fff" />
            )}
          </Buttons>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </PlayButtonContainer>
    );
  }
}

const PlayButtonContainer = styled.View`
  width: 90;
  height: 100;
  background-color: #224c87;
  text-align: center;
`;

const Buttons = styled.Text`
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 13px;
  text-align: center;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the `componentDidMount` method be `async` shouldn't cause an issue, since it's the last lifecycle method anyway. However, if you create your own `async` functions, you have to handle them as promises: either by using `then()` or `await`. For instance, your `loadAudio` function is also marked as `async`, but when you call it in `componentDidMount`, there is no `await` nor `then()`.

---

But this is not what causes your problem here. If you pass the `streamURL` as a `prop`, you should be able to access it in any of the functions as `this.props.streamURL`. Your problem is caused by `this`. If you want to access the `props` of your `React.Component`, you have to bind `this` to the function in the `constructor`.

Like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isPlaying: false,
            playbackInstance: null,
            currentIndex: 0,
            volume: 1.0,
            isBuffering: true,
        };

        this.loadAudio = this.loadAudio.bind(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this only confuses me more. I am fairly newb to react and my understand of 'this' and 'constructors' is still meager at best.

Comment: @MarcPope I recommend you take a look at react hooks. Using those, you don't have to deal with classes or constructors